# Compiling numpy with external libraries for super computer

Tags: python, numpy, atlas

I am compiling numpy and get an error so I think I need to include external libraries. The atlas installation is in /usr/lib64/atlas. Since I don't have access to root I have everything installed in my home directory including python 2.6.7.

I am assuming I change the site.cfg file but do I only need to add the /usr/lib64/atlas to the libraries directory.

They also have ptcblas and ptf77blas are these supported in numpy??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably get this to work by setting CFLAGS and LDFLAGS before you run `pip install numpy` so that it uses your own personal library directory.

```
CFLAGS='-l/home/me/include'
LDFLAGS='-L/home/me/lib'
```

If that doesn't work, find a machine (or a VM) where you can build tools and access /usr/lib, then follow the script in this question [Compiling Python 2.6.6 and need for external packages wxPython, setuptools, etc... in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079128/compiling-python-2-6-6-and-need-for-external-packages-wxpython-setuptools-etc/6606432#6606432) to build your own portable Python distro including the libraries you need. Just delete any parts of the script that build modules which you will never use, and add any additional modules that you need. If you add modules, make sure that you run the strace checks at the end.