# Suitability of deploying python 2.7 apps using external (PyPi) packages in major hosts

Tags: python, web-hosting

I am writing a python program for processing files (no DJango involved). I need ZODB3 and Whoosh which are hosted on http://pypi.python.org. It needs to be deployed in a major host like Bluehost or Hostgator.

My questions are:

1. Can I depend on reliable Python 2.7 support from major hosts?
2. Can they support other packages (one host has a list of supported packages and tells us to         contact tech support for more packages), especially if it is available from the easy_install interface?
3. Is it a pain to set up?
4. Will my choice of ZODB (object persistence library, part of ZOPE) cause problems?

It seems a dumb question, but it can probably save weeks of my time.

Some relevant details:
Its only for file processing, no DJango required. ZODB is for object persistence. I dont need to back up the ZODB store as it can be readily reconstructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot depend on any kind of Python support from any hoster or any operating system. Build your own portable Python distro and include all the 3rd party modules that you will need. Then you have one tarball to install on any Linux VM and everything just works. You also avoid breaking OS tools that depend on Python such as Webmin because you have your own separate Python and never touch the system default one.

[Compiling Python 2.6.6 and need for external packages wxPython, setuptools, etc... in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079128/compiling-python-2-6-6-and-need-for-external-packages-wxpython-setuptools-etc/6606432#6606432)

Comment: Wow. That's how you do it on major hosts?

Comment: That's how I do it at work on development machines too. I am developing apps, not deploying operating system services. I want all of my app's dependencies to be under my control, not the sys admins or some remote developer or PyPi site admin. One app equal one tarball unpacked in one directory with *ALL* dependencies including libc and ld-linux.so.2. Works on all versions of Linux.

Comment: I remember going through my mercurial install in windows and seeing a python installation. I understand now.